# POST input type="number" inside a Loop and SUM its total

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, sum

So I have this Shopping Cart in this loop that displays the Products and Price from Database and each row has a input type="number" called Quantity. What I want is: when I click a submit button or a href called "proceed to payment" I want  the price to multiply to the quantity of each row, returning a totalPrice.

This is my code so far but it isn't working:

```
$query = "select * from Cart where id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
$res=mysqli_query($lig,$query) or die ("error");
$nr=mysqli_num_rows($res);
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<$nr;$i++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo "Product: " . $row['product'];
    echo "Price: " . $row['price'];
    Quantity: &nbsp <input type="number" name="quantity"
    $quantity += $quantity + $_POST['quantity'];
    echo "</tr>";
}
<a href="confirmPayment.php?quantity=<?php echo $quantity;?>
```

Comment: How are you co-relating a product and it's corresponding quantity from HTML form? Please include your HTML form in the question as well.

Comment: Real urgent: Hire hackhands or something like that.

Comment: Work through your code line by line logically - there are a LOT of issues - e.g., `$quantity += $quanitity + $_POST['quantity']` should be `$quantity = $quantity + $_POST['quantity']` or `$quantity += $_POST['quantity']`; you can't have one field `$_POST['quantity']` for multiple line items in the cart; confirmPayment should probably be another form post and not an href (which is a get), etc.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is searching and wants an answer at least on the part about how to get a subtotal for price * quantity, and total for all items, this works for me:

```
<?php 

    $query = "select * from Cart where id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
    $res = mysqli_query($lig,$query) or die ("error");
    $total = 0;
    echo "<table><tr><th>Product:</th><th>Price:</th><th>Quantity:</th><th>Subtotal:</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
        $subtotal = $row['quantity'] * $row['price'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='number' min='0' name='quantity' value='" . $row['quantity'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $subtotal . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $total = $total + $subtotal;
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<a href='confirmPayment.php?quantity=" .$total ."'>Confirm pay " . $total ."</a>";

?>
```

Basically, all I do is initialize the Total, create a subtotal inside the loop, and add that subtotal to the Total. It looks a little cleaner this way also. My output looks like this:

[image: Picture of my version running...]

Comment: TBowman yeah but you are getting the "quantity" value from $row['quantity'] assuming it's stored in the db, and my problem is that, the variable quantity isn't stored anywhere, it is just based on the user input. But thanks for the efford.

Comment: So, you have a table that stores Cart data, but doesn't store the quantity of each of the products they are ordering? That seems odd.

Comment: @TBowman Based on `$_POST['quantity']` it looks like quantity is supposed to be an HTML field. But that would be just **one** item, not all the items in the database. Needs to be a field that includes identification of the item so that the quantity is matched to the correct item & price.